# GMSMapView Energy Impact

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I'm currently using a GMSMapView in my swift app, and the energy impact is never decreasing ( as the CPU usage or Memory usage ).

Did anyone already faced this issue ?

Using Google Maps 2.0.1

[image: Xcode Monitoring]

[image: Energy impact]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Found the answer myself. It is related to `GMSMarker.tracksViewChanges` property.

Turning it to `false` for all added markers has released the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Make `false` of `GMSMarker()`'s object property `tracksViewChanges` & `tracksInfoWindowChanges`

```
let placeMarker = GMSMarker()
placeMarker.tracksViewChanges = false
placeMarker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = false
```

It will bringdown energy impact clock indictor.

Comment: I was already using tracksViewChanges property but now added tracksInfoWindowChanges as false, and that is showing significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I found google maps to consume to much memory as well. Changing tracksViewChanges worked for me as well.

Another approach that I have tried when the rendering was taking to long, is to split the rendering of the markers or views in the map.

You can use the delegate methods of GMSMapView

- `mapViewDidStartTileRendering(_mapView: GMSMapView)` and
- `mapViewDidFinishTileRendering(_ mapView: GMSMapView)`

to know when the render has finished and add new elements.